# MySQL and UNIX_TIMESTAMP insert error

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with a project I am currently working on, built in PHP & MySQL. The project itself is similar to an online bidding system. Users bid on a project, and they get a chance to win if they follow their bid by clicking and cliking again.

The problem is this: if 5 users for example, enter the game at the same time, I get a 8-10 seconds delay in the database - I update the database using the UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), which makes the whole system of the bids useless.

I want to mention too that the project is very database intensive (around 30-40 queries per page) and I was thinking maybe the queries get delayed, but I'm not sure if that's happening. If that's the case though, any suggestions how to avoid this type of problem?

Hope I've been at least clear with this issue. It's the first time it happened to me and I would appreciate your help!

Comment: Your question is a bit vague but it sounds like you have some slow running queries you need to optimise. You might want to look in to using the slow query log. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html

Comment: Why not calculate the current timestamp in PHP and insert it into the database? Then the database lag doesn't matter.

Comment: This is very vague. Please support your question with some code.

Comment: So you don't get an insert error as the title suggests?

Comment: mysql timestamps have a 1 second granularity. that's not good enough for a multi-user bidding system. you WILL get collisions. While normally I advocate using the db for as much as possible, in this case you may want to get a microsecond timestamp in PHP using microtime() instead.

Comment: You probably need to optimize your MySQL settings. What machine are you running on, what are your settings and do you have some notion of the cpu / memory / disk utilization by MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can decide on

1. Optimizing or minimizing required queries.
2. You can cache queries do not need to update on each visit.
3. You can use Summery tables
4. Update the queries only on changes.

You have to do this cleverly. You can follow this MySQLPerformanceBlog

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clearly on what you're doing, but let me elaborate on what you said. If you're using UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) in your MySQL query you have a serious problem.

The problem with your approach is that you are using MySQL functions to supply the timestamp record that will be stored in the database. This is an issue, because then you have to wait on MySQL to parse and execute your query before that timestamp is ever generated (and some MySQL engines like MyISAM use table-level locking). Other engines (like InnoDB) have slower writes due to row-level locking granularity. This means the time stored in the row will not necessarily reflect the time the request was generated to insert said row. Additionally, it can also mean that the time you're reading from the database is not necessarily the most current record (*assuming you are updating records after they were inserted into the table*).

What you need is for the PHP request that generates the SQL query to provide the TIMESTAMP directly in the SQL query. This means the timestamp reflects the time the request is received by PHP and not necessarily the time that the row is inserted/updated into the database.

You also have to be clear about which MySQL engine you're table is using. For example, engines like InnoDB use [MVCC](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-multi-versioning.html) (*Multi-Version Concurrency Control*). This means while a row is being read it can be written to at the same time. If this happens the database engine uses something called a page table to store the existing value that will be read by the client while the new value is being updated. That way you have guaranteed row-level locking with faster and more stable reads, but potentially slower writes.